# How to keep track of signals and slots in Qt?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

This question is not directly about programming, but I hope that it still fits here: When programming with Qt I have the problem that after some times my subclasses are getting extremely large which leads to a lot of signals and slots in each class I have to connect later. Therefore I was wondering if there is a simple possibility to keep track of all the signals and slots, for example to tell me if I forgot to connect a signal, or to show me all connections of one signal if it is connected more than once. Is there a tool or a function in Qt for that, or should I rather stay with pen & paper for keeping track of them?

Comment: One of the tools you can use is [QSignalSpy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsignalspy.html) from QtTest module

Comment: To make sure you haven't forgot to connect a signal to a slot just test your application - it will discover most of the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conan](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Conan+-+Connection+analyzer+for+Qt?content=108330) is a C++ library that provides run-time introspection of object
hierarchies, object inheritance, signal/slot connections, and signal
emissions.

[GammaRay](http://www.kdab.com/kdab-products/gammaray/) is another advanced analyser which can show signals/slots.